# Dynamically Populate APP_BASE_HREF in Angular 4: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular

I am trying to dynamically populate the `APP_BASE_HREF` and running into an error when trying to compile. I am using Angular CLI to compile (ng build)

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 95:21 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in
>   C:/Dev/Web/src/app/app.module.ts`

**app.module.ts**

```typescript
import { SimpleService } from './simple-service';

   providers: [
      SimpleService,
      {
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useFactory: (simpleservice: SimpleService) => {
          return simpleservice.getBaseHref();
        },
        deps: [ SimpleService]
      }
    ],
```

**simple-service.ts**

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SimpleService 
{
    getBaseHref(): string {
        return '/';
    }
}
```